# Changing CRS of downloaded shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have looked through all the other questions which might have received answers to the question I am currently posting. However, after trying all their recommendations I am still stuck with the same issue.

I have downloaded data which provided shape files with are set within the coordinate reference system (CRS) as **EPSG:4230 - ED50**. I need this shapefile in the CRS of **EPSG:4326 - WGS 84**.

I have tried `adding new vector layer` with the downloaded data shapefile. I then saved the file with the CRS that I desire. When I upload it again it still is recorded as **EPSG:4230 - ED50**, does anyone know why I cant change it. I am using QGIS versions 3.2